# Операторы сдвига и побитовое НЕ JAVA

Tags: java, операторы

Опыты ставились над переменной int number.
К двоичному виду приводил при помощи Integer.toBinaryString(number);

Пример #1: Операторы сдвига

Теория:
10001010  - значение
10001010>>1
11000101      - результат

Практика:
1111111111111111111111101111010       значение
1111111111111111111111101111010>>1
1111111111111111111111110111101      ожидание
111111111111111111111110111101       реальность

Пример #2: побитовое НЕ(NOT)

Теория:
~00001001                          -выражение
00001001  -значение
11110110                          -результат

Практика:
~1111111111111111111111111111111       выражение
1111111111111111111111111111111    значение
000000000000000000000000000       ожидание
1000000000000000000000000000      реальность

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Практика:
1111111111111111111111101111010 значение
1111111111111111111111101111010>>1
1111111111111111111111110111101 ожидание
111111111111111111111110111101 реальность
```

откуда в вашем ожидании появилась новая единица слева?

> При выполнении сдвига вправо старшие (расположенные в крайних левых
>   позициях) биты, освобожденные в результате сдвига, заполняются
>   предыдущим содержимым старшего бита.

[источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/bitwise.php)

Поскольку у вас отображено 31 бит, значит 32 бит равен нулю, и при сдивге вправо именно он сдвигается и снова не отображается. А его место так же занимает ноль

```
Практика:
~1111111111111111111111111111111 выражение
1111111111111111111111111111111 значение
000000000000000000000000000 ожидание
1000000000000000000000000000 реальность
```

int содержит 4 байта по 8 бит = 32 бита.

В вашем случае "выражение" содержит 31 единицу, и 1 невидимый ноль в начале (java не выводит нули в начале).

Соответственно когда вы 31 единицу перевернули, так же перевернулся и первый бит, который в выражении равен нулю.

В итоговом выражении первый ноль стал единицей, а все единицы стали нулями.

Comment: Пересчитался, рассуждал исходя из того что крайний левый это 32-й, а не 31-й. Спасибо большое!